# Google Cloud Message - Notification USB Behavior

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Sorry, my english is not so good... anyway.

I have a android application that uses GCM to receive push notifications.

Steps:
1 - User click logon button 
2 - Android app save the registration ID ( Working )
3 - Send to WebService and put in database ( Working)
4 - Server Application (C#) send the message for selected registration id ( Working)

5 - Device receive the notification normally, BUT just if device is CONNECTED
ON USB (*** PROBLEM *** )

if i dont connect the device on usb, i receive the notification but with a 
blank message.

i'm blocked for one week .. someone can help me ? Plz..

public class GCMNotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

```
public static  int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GCMNotificationIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

public static final String TAG = "GCMNotificationIntentService";

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Log.i(TAG,
                        "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }

            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            sendNotification(""+ extras.get(Config.MESSAGE_KEY));
            Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Preparing to send notification...: " + msg);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Uri alarmSound2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"  + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.mario);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, lucasbergamo.minha_granna.Android.ac_Login.class), 0);

    String date = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.coin_notification)
            .setContentTitle("Minha Granna - ")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500)
            .setVibrate(pattern)
            .setSound(alarmSound2)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle())
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    if (NOTIFICATION_ID > 1073741824) {
        NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
    }

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification sent successfully.");
}
```

}

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GCMNotificationIntentService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

```
<application
    android:name="lucasbergamo.minha_granna.Entidades.User"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icones_indicador_financeiro"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity
        android:name=".ac_Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ac_Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >

        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="lucasbergamo.minha_granna.Notification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />


</application>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<permission
    android:name="lucasbergamo.minha_granna.Notification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />


<uses-permission android:name="lucasbergamo.minha_granna.Notification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

I receive the notification only if the usb cable is attached...if not i will receive blank message.

Thanks!!!!

bergamo86@gmail.com
skype  lucazin

Comment: Check the MSGReceiver and MSGSerice (or corresponding) class that receives the message from GCM server. You check print and see if you are receiving null. May be the variable names used there and the one you are sending from your MVC are different.

Comment: You can also try [**this**](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/490974/PushSharpplus-plusAndroidplusGCMpluspushplusnotifi)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! the package name are different ! so i fix this issue just setting the current package.

Thanks all!